# Why is my question posted as an answer removed?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

There is a question about a particular cmake problem concerning building support for a compiler. I struggle with the same problem that's why I stumbled upon this rather old communication.

The guy who posted the question states that he has been helped with the hints that were given but it's unclear if he succeeded in the whole; that is building support for that compiler by cmake.
In the latest cmake version there is still no support for this compiler so clearly he didn't contribute there.

So I added a question to him if he succeeded and if he can share his (partial) result so that other (like me) can use/continue the quest. This was removed and I don't understand why it is removed.

I think it has added value because:
- it indicates other people struggle with the same - encouraging people to provide more info when they have it
- it could hint the original poster to share his results (if any) which could be very usefull for others and serve a future reference

Maybe some one can let me know why this happens and take away my frustration.

The post concerned is this one: [Changing parameters for include files with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533962/changing-parameters-for-include-files-with-cmake/62086137#62086137)

Comment: Because we actually want *answers* in the answer space.

Comment: Because SO isn’t a discussion board. SO is not a forum. SO is a strictly Q&A site. The answer to your question is contained in your own title: *why was my **question** posed as an **answer** removed?*. Because it *was not an answer*. The only things that should be posted in reply to *questions* is answers. If you want to “indicate other people struggle with the same” - upvote the question; that’s exactly what upvotes are for. As for “encouraging and hinting” - use comments; that’s what comments are for. If you don’t have the rep to comment yet, go earn it first, by posting Q&A.

Comment: @DanBron _“If you want to ‘indicate other people struggle with the same’ — upvote the question; that’s exactly what upvotes are for”_ — No; upvotes on questions are for “This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear”, as the title text says. You don’t upvote the one thousandth _“Halp, how I resolve NullPointerException”_ question just because lots of people struggle with the same problem.

Comment: Because asking questions as an answer to a question makes it impossible to answer that question?  Since it doesn’t answer the question, then the answer is unhelpful, unhelpful contributions should be deleted immediately.

Comment: OK, I get it. So asking a question is not allowed. However my intent was to make the post complete in that sense that it can help future readers. Without the solution it is worthless and I asked the OP if she/he can share the solution. I see you guys pin-point me to the rules but you don elaborate on my intent - which is to improve the post.

Answer (score 22):

Your post was removed because it was not an answer. The concept of an "answer" on Stack Overflow is a bit more narrow than it is on many sites. Here, an answer must *answer the question asked*. Answers are not "discussion" opportunities.

Asking the question asker for additional information can be done in comments, but you need 50 reputation to add a comment to someone else's post. Please read: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/336163)

Please see here to learn about what exactly are subject to summary deletion under our "Not An Answer" rules - [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/6471538)

If you posted your question as an answer because you have been banned from asking questions, please read: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/6471538)

Comment: This comment was very helpful to me because its so complete, thank you Robert! I try to aim for 50 points then.